# Thread not seeing global boolean

Tags: .net, vb.net

For some reason, I cannot get the thread to end when calling Thread.Join(). Am I crazy?

```
Public Sub StartThread()
    _opsthread = New Thread(AddressOf OpsThread)
    _opsthread.IsBackground = True
    _opsthread.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub StopThread()
    _continue = False
    _opsthread.Join()
    'Application Hangs Here
End Sub

Public Sub OpsThread()
    While _continue
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested the code as written and was not able to reproduce the hang.  I agree that access to the continue flag should be done differently.

Comment: I'm sorry, I simplified the code because I figured no one would want to read 3 pages of code that no matter how hard I try has no elegance.

Comment: Then the simplified version doesn't represent the problem.

Comment: Yes you are correct. If I included my global declaration of _continue it would have shown the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the test I ran, slightly modified.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    StartThread()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    StopThread()
End Sub

Dim _opsthread As Threading.Thread
Dim _continue As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)

Public Sub StartThread()
    _continue.Reset()
    _opsthread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf OpsThread)
    _opsthread.IsBackground = True
    _opsthread.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub StopThread()
    If IsNothing(_opsthread) Then Exit Sub
    _continue.Set()
    _opsthread.Join()
    'Application Hangs Here
    ' Debug.WriteLine("end")
End Sub

Public Sub OpsThread()
    Dim cont As Boolean = False
    While Not cont
        cont = _continue.WaitOne(1000)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: I declared continue like this: Private _continue as boolean

Comment: I redefined to take care of synchronization.

Comment: It's working now! I changed _continue from a global boolean to an autoresetevent and problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't synchronized access to `_continue`. For that reason it was probably enregistered by the JIT. Synchronize access to it (for example using `Thread.MemoryBarrier`) before reading it and after writing it.

Sharing data without synchronization is always a red flag. Be it because the program becomes buggy or be it because most people do not understand the rules well enough to make sure it is safe (I certainly don't - so I don't do it).

Comment: Do you have an example? Thanks.